# chrome padding percenage + width percentage not adding together

Tags: css, google-chrome

In firefox, my results are as expected. I am attempting to add `width` and `padding` to make up the full size. In chrome this doesnt seem to be working,

```
.tab-content {

padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
width:100% !important;
```

}

In firefox this causes it to go 110% (what Id be expecting) , in chrome 100%, 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 100% in CSS2 it means that the final width of the element (not the CSS width) will be: border-left + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-right.

So in your case it is interpreted as 110%:

0 + 5% + 100% + 5% + 0 = 110%

A perfect solution could be:

```
.tab-content {
    padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
    width:90%;
}
```

You can use *box-sizing* property of CSS3 BUT it has some bugs due to how to interpret it. **I don't recommend use it**. If it is used the CSS width property will included borders and paddings.

Comment: Thanks but the problem was that the 90% only worked on firefox, in the end I used `box-sizing` as it was the only solution I could find, and its only one small area of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-webkit-box-sizing`, it could be that causing an issue.

More info at [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)